# Cell vs battery discharge curve

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I have a battery pack composed of 16 cells in series.

(Battery pack link: https://www.innopower.de/produkt/innopower-lfp-105ah-eve-battery-pack/

Cell link: https://www.innopower.de/produkt/innopower-lfmp-105ah/# )

The manufacturer gives the cell's specifications and discharge curve (plot on the left).
Is the battery pack discharge curve simply the cell's curve but the voltage multiplied by 16? (plot on the right)
[image]

Since it's a 1P16S scheme the capacity remains the same, the voltage gets multiplied by 16 and so does the resistance. Therefore, can I assume that the discharge curve is simply "scaled up"?

Comment: "Since it's a 1P8S scheme the capacity remains the same, the voltage gets multiplied by 16". I think you meant to say "16S", not "8S".

Comment: Ups my mistake, you're right! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the battery pack discharge curve simply the cell's curve but the voltage multiplied by 16?

Yes, in the ideal case that the battery is balanced and all the cells have the same capacity.

If the battery is not balanced (some of the cells in series are more charged than others), then the battery curve will be a narrower (left and right) portion because the left end of the graph is not reachable without overcharging the most charged cells, and the right end of the graph is not reachable without over-discharging the most discharged cells

If the cell capacities vary, then the curve will be squeezed to the right, according to the capacity of the lowest capacity cell.

---

By the way, the x-axis of those graphs is mislabeled: it should say "Charge (Ah)" not "Capacity (Ah)". The capacity is a single point on the right-most end of the curve.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the additional information! Have a nice day